# How can I "move" GRUB?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, mbr

I had the following setup on my hard disk

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Windows (100 GB)  |  Precise (20 GB) | Documents (~ 360 GB)     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to move to LVM. I have deleted Windows and created a small partition to hold `/boot`.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| boot(512MB) | LVM (99GB) | Precise (20GB) | Documents (~ 360GB) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But as I am migrating the installed Ubuntu installation (no fresh install), I am wondering how can I move GRUB there. I have already copied everything from `/boot` to that partition.

As GRUB is installed on MBR, there is some step needed so GRUB will use that new partition (and the menu/kernels there)? Also how GRUB finds the menu (ie how he knows that the OS entries are in `(Precise partition)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`)?

Comment: you do understand that you have to do more then "move grub"? You have to update /etc/fstab to add /boot and you have to configure LVM, then you need to rebuild your initramfs ? If you do not know all the steps it is going to be much much easier for you to do a fresh install. And with the size of your hard drive, 512 mb is much too small for /boot, I would give it 5 Gb (although that is a little large).

Comment: Did you try something like 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda1' followed by 'sudo update-grub'?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you don't need a dedicated /boot partition; you can just leave /boot in your lvm root volume.  Either way, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` to reinstall it.